# New Firebase SDK 3: Serialize string via DataSnapshot.getValue(Class<T> aClass)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

With the old Firebase SDK, the DataSnapshot.getValue(Class aClass) method was capable of taking a simple string value from the database like:

```
"id": "name"
```

And return a POJO instance, if the given class had only one property named `String value`. This allowed for nicely reusable implementation of a `FirebaseAdapter`, that could handle complex objects, as well as simple strings at the same time. Maybe the behavior in the old SDK was unintentional and isn't working anymore due to some changes in the code base. 
Any suggestions for a workaround besides creating an entirely new adapter?

**EDIT: Complete example**
This JSON fragment represents my whole database:

```
{
  "test" : {
    "id" : "value"
  }
}
```

Then I query this entry using the following code, which only contains relevant code in `onChildAdded` in order to be as simple as possible:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://<MYPROJECT>.firebaseio.com");
Query query = ref.child("test");
query.addChildEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Record record = dataSnapshot.getValue(Record.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

With the POJO `Record` looking like this:

```
public class Record {
    private String value;

    public Record() { }
    public Record(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

With the old JSON mapping using a property named 'value' and a constructor with one string argument worked. Now getValue(Record.class) crashes with

> Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type
>   com.journeytags.journeytagsandroid.model.Record.

Of course, getting a single string with this construct seems unnecessary, however, I use this in a generic context, which helps me to avoid additional code for this special case.

Comment: The basic POJO-from/to-JSON mapping still works in the latest SDK, but we reduced the SDK size by removing the dependency on Jackson. If you're having problems, post a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows us to reproduce your problem. This would include JSON (as text, no screenshot), the code of a minimal POJO that shows the problem (no more properties than are needed please), the code that listens for changes and how you process them, and the stack trace of the error you are getting (of any).

Comment: Data under the root node of my firebase database http://pastie.org/10864159
Then I query this entry with http://pastie.org/10864158. The model class 'Record' is just this POJO object here http://pastie.org/10864160.
With the old JSON mapping using a property named 'value' and a constructor worked. Now `getValue(Record.class)` crashes with `Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.journeytags.journeytagsandroid.model.Record`. Of course, getting a single string with this construct seems unnecessary, but, I use this in a generic context, which helps me to avoid additional code.

Comment: Can you add the code and JSON to the question itself instead of in links? Also show how you call `getValue()` and what ref you use.

Comment: I added everything to the original question.